# Update a column based on the primary id in this order

Tags: sql, group-by, sql-update

Here is the test code. I would like the city_id to be updated such that the city_id must must match the *first* id of that city that appears in select statement. Example. Here I would like the city_id [last column] to be 1,1,3,3

[image]

```
create table student2 (id int not null primary key  identity,
city_name varchar(25),
student_name varchar(25),
city_id int  null)


insert into student2 values('Boston','Nome',null) 
insert into student2 values('Boston','Tiger',null) 
insert into student2 values('Miami','Andy',null) 
insert into student2 values('Miami','Moran',null)
```

Two query's are fine if that does the job. I have obviously large number of records. Creating temporary table and outputting the result to text file is fine too. In that case you would print id and city_id

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like this:

```
update student2
set city_id =
    (select min(id) from student2 s where s.city_name = student2.city_name)
```

Good luck!

Comment: +1 for answer, -0.5 for encouraging databases that are not normalized ;)

Comment: No, see my comment on D.N.'s answer where I explain the difference.  :)

Answer (score 2):

The best approach is to create a new table called `cities`, that contains columns `city_id` and `city_name`.  This is called normalizing the database, and reduces the complexity of your problem.

For your example, you would have:

```
id |city_id |student_name
1  |1       |Nome
2  |1       |Tiger
3  |2       |Andy
4  |2       |Moran

city_id |city_name
1       |Boston
2       |Miami
```

Comment: Agreed -- if you have the ability to model the data differently, have mercy and do as D.N. suggests.  If you do not, refer to my example code.

Comment: That *is* the right approach but the city_id column in your output should read 1,1,3,3, not 1,1,2,2. At least in our present design. Unless you encourage yours.

Comment: I strongly encourage the redesign, even with greater effort.  There's many reasons why duplicating information is a bad idea.

Comment: Especially as, if you leave the table as it is, you have to ensure that the ID is always synced to the city.  @Dave your setup is a nightmare that may require you to update *every* row in the table, when changing the city of only *one* student...  Also, you seem to think that the `city_id` is populated from the first instance of the `student_id` that contained it - this is wrong, `city_id` is it's own incrementing value, which has **no** relation whatsoever to the `student_id`.

Comment: well this is just an example. I have different real case scenario. We dont touch these IDs once we create them. And btw city_id is not actually any id or an incrementing one. It is just a number that means a particular city.